# Is there any way to read/get pin mode using python (and wiringPi)

Tags: gpio, python, wiringpi, sqlite

I have a database with table *pins* with atributes *pinNo*, *pinMode* and *pinState*. I'm trying to read these raspberry pi's atributes using wiringPi in python script, and to write that data into the table in the database. I'm wondering how can I read/get pin mode? I've been searching over the internet and reading wiringPi's documentation but I haven't found any method implemented for this purpose. Is there any way to do this "manually" using python?

Comment: Which documentation have you read?  I am surprised you can not find the information you need.

Comment: I've been searching through the reference on wiringpi.com..

Comment: You got an answer to the question you actually asked.  How to use a database in python, and/or how to parse data and place it into one, are basic programming questions unrelated to the pi and as such belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Please explain to me how its not related to the pi, when I actually need to get mode of the certain pin ??? I know how to use a database in python, but I dont know how to get information RELATED TO PI, that I need to store in the db.

Comment: See also this Q&A: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/can-we-determine-the-mode-of-a-gpio-pin

Answer (score 2):

Using `WiringPi`: `gpio readall` will return the state of all of the pins.

Comment: yes it will return the state of all of the pins, but how can I use that to store wanted information into the db..